# How can I check if my UILabel value is above 0?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

How can I check if my UILabel value is above 0? I just need to do an if statement. I am doing this because I need to find out if the number is 1, 2, 3 etc and then if it is, I need to call a certain action.

I have tried the following code but it does not work and instead shows an error:

if ([[label text] intValue] > 0){

}

**EDIT:** I found another piece of code which was provoking this not to work. The code above now fully works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ([[myLabel text] intValue] > 0) ...
```

Comment: this error appears: http://pastie.org/2956098

Comment: @pixelbitlabs This isn't from this snippet. Look for a place in your code where you call `isEqualToString` on an instance of `UILabel`; there is no such method on UILabel.

Comment: How can I find out what exactly is causing it as I can't see anything which uses isEqualToString and is a UILabel...

Comment: @pixelbitlabs This error also happens when you assign new value to UILabel's text. If you try assigning `myLabel.text = otherLabel` instead of `myLabel.text = otherLabel.text`, you'll get that error.

Comment: I've checked, nothing in my code is like that. It's really weird :(

Comment: @pixelbitlabs Try stepping through your app. If that's not possible, comment out enough code to make the error go away, then start uncommenting until you hit the error again.

Comment: All works now, I found that there was another bit of code which was confusing everything. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the text value of the UILabel is numeric, you could just do this:

```
- (BOOL)valueGreaterThanZero:(UILabel *)label {
    NSString *text = [label text];
    int value;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:text] scanInt:&value];
    return (value > 0);
}
```

Beware, though, that this will crash with a non-numeric value.

Better version, with error handling... this assumes that you want a false value for non-numerics:

```
- (BOOL)valueGreaterThanZero:(UILabel *)label {
    NSString *text = [label text];
    int value;
    BOOL gotNumber = [[NSScanner scannerWithString:text] scanInt:&value];
    return (gotNumber && value > 0);
}
```

Then, to use in an if statement, as per OP,

```
if ([self valueGreaterThanZero:labelToCheck]) ...
```

Comment: how can I call this function?

Comment: this error appears: http://pastie.org/2956098

Comment: You've got a problem with an 'isEqualToString:(NSString *)' call, which I didn't provide in my code. Fix that and then try my code again. Also, the way I'd probably implement this is to sub-class UILabel and add the function above to the sub-class. Then (assuming 'myLabel' is an instance of that sub-class), you could do this `if ([myLabel valueGreaterThanZero])...`. Of course, to do this, you'd change the function signature to remove the `:(UILabel *)label` portion. So, the final signature would be `- (BOOL)valueGreaterThanZero`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([myLabel.text intValue] > 0) {
    // do staf
}
```

Comment: this error appears: http://pastie.org/2956098